# Com CSS é possível fazer um triângulo com bordas curvas?

Tags: css, css3, css-shape

Minha intenção é chegar nessa forma. Apenas com CSS sem SVG.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém tem alguma solução para isso?

O código que tenho até o momento é esse.

```css
#tri { 
    width: 0;
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 0px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 75px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="tri"></div>
```

Comment: Acho que com border-radius você consegue fazer essas bordas curvas.

Comment: Com border-radius dá para fazer os vértices da base mas não afeta o vértice do topo. Vai precisar um segundo `div`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques possivelmente com mais umas divs e border-radius de para fazer, talvez seja um caminho

Comment: Um exemplo do soEN de como atingir o objetivo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446677/how-to-make-3-corner-rounded-triangle-in-css, se alguém quiser traduzir pra enriquecer o conteúdo do soPT sinta-se a vontade :)

Comment: Fiz a tradução porque achei a resposta muito criativa.

Comment: @MarceloBoni valeu a dica

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ideia é realmente simples: você primeiro aplica uma série de transformações ao seu elemento `.triangle` (com o atributo `overflow: hidden` que você pode removê-lo para ver o que está acontecendo) para obter um losango.

Em seguida, você aplica as mesmas transformações aos pseudo-elementos `:before` e `:after`, torná-las um pouco mais romboidais.

E no final, você tem três losangos que se cruzam, a forma laranja sendo a interseção deles. Passe o mouse triângulo para ver as formas que se cruzam.

A figura é escalonável, bastando alterar a largura e a altura do elemento `.triangle`.

Para Firefox, Chrome e Safari, apenas o triângulo laranja com cantos arredondados é sensível ao passar do mouse (graças a `pointer-events: none;` no elemento `.triangle` e `pointer-events: auto;` nos pseudo-elementos). De outra forma pode ser alcançado envolvendo `.triangle` em um elemento com a mesma largura e altura (e o mesmo raio da borda) com `overflow: hidden;`.

```css
.triangle, .triangle:before, .triangle:after { width: 4em; height: 4em; }
.triangle {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin: 7em auto 0;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transform: translateY(50%) rotate(30deg) skewY(30deg) scaleX(.866);
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: none;
} 
.triangle:before, .triangle:after {
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
    pointer-events: auto;
    content: '';
}
.triangle:before {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 20% 53%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(-24%);
}
.triangle:after {
    border-radius: 20% 20% 53% 20%;
    transform: scaleX(1.155) skewY(-30deg) rotate(-30deg) translateY(-42.3%) 
            skewX(-30deg) scaleY(.866) translateX(24%);
}

/** extra styles to show how it works **/

.triangle:hover { overflow: visible; }
.triangle:hover:before, .triangle:hover:after { background: none; }
.triangle:hover, .triangle:hover:before, .triangle:hover:after {
    border: dashed 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class='triangle'></div>
```

Traduzido do [Stack Overflow EN How to make 3-corner-rounded triangle in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14448027/11379709)

Comment: Cara é bem criativa mesmo essa solução, até dei uma estudada nela para entender melhor, coloquei um contorno na div pai, e cor com transparência nos pseudo-elementos e deu pra entender ainda melhor o que foi feito https://imgur.com/oH1AJYP valeu a contribuição